# Why does mapTo fail in Akka HTTP client?

Tags: scala, akka, spray, akka-http, spray-client

I have a Akka HTTP service which returns a string, as shown below:

```
val route1: Route = {
    path("hello") {
      get{
        complete{
          println("Inside r1")
          "You just accessed hello"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

I have a Akka HTTP client which tries to access this route. But the below code fails:

```
  val future1 = Http()
    .singleRequest(
      HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.GET,
        uri = "http://localhost:8187/hello")).mapTo[String]

  future1.onSuccess({
    case y:String=>println(y)
  })
```

I get no output at all. But, if I use unmarshal instead with a flatMap, I get the output:

```
 val future1:Future[String] = Http()
    .singleRequest(
      HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.GET,
                  uri = "http://localhost:8187/hello")).flatMap(resp => Unmarshal(resp).to[String])
```

Why is mapTo failing here and why do I need flatMap and Unmarshal?

Edit:

I understood the need for Unmarhsal  and I am trying to understand the difference between map and flatMap

For example, the below code gives me the result as expected:

```
val future1:Future[String] = Http().singleRequest(
          HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.GET,
                      uri = http://localhost:8187/hello")).flatMap(testFlatFunc)

  def testFlatFunc(x:HttpResponse):Future[String]={
    return Unmarshal(x).to[String]
  }
```

But, if I try to replace it with a map, as below I get the output as `FulfilledFuture(You just accessed hello)`

```
 val future1:Future[String] = Http()
    .singleRequest(
      HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.GET,
                  uri = "http://localhost:8187/hello")).map(testFunc)

  def testFunc(x:HttpResponse): String={
    return Unmarshal(x).to[String].toString
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the docs for `mapTo` below

```
  /** Creates a new `Future[S]` which is completed with this `Future`'s result if
   *  that conforms to `S`'s erased type or a `ClassCastException` otherwise.
   */
```

`mapTo[S]` essentially corresponds to a cast. The `Http().singleRequest` produces a `Future[HttpResponse]`, and `HttpResponse` cannot be bluntly cast to `String`.

Umarshalling is necessary to specify a meaningful logic to convert to `String`. So in your case you have an implicit `Unmarshaller` in scope that provides this. And this is most likely the default `stringUnmarshaller` from Akka-HTTP predefined set. More info on this can be found in the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/unmarshalling.html#predefined-unmarshallers).